# signalR - how to call server method from client - code not working

Tags: asp.net, signalr

When I try calling SendNewOrderConfirmation on the server side from the client I get

> "undefined" is not a function

on line  `chat.SendNewOrderConfirmation(data);`
does anyone know why is this happening? 
Thank you

on the server side

```
public class DriverChat : Hub, IDisconnect
{

    public void Start(Driver d)
    {
     ...
     }
    public void SendNewOrderConfirmation(OrderDriverData data)
    {
        LogFile.LogResponseTime(data.orderId, data.driverId);
    }
}
```

on the client side

```
 function begin(args) {

        try {
            //alert('begin');

            chat = $.connection.driverChat;

            chat.refresh = function () {
                ready++;
            };
            chat.disconnect = function () {
                alert('Server has disconnected');
            };
            $.connection.hub.start(function () {
                chat.start(args);
                ready++;
               // alert('signalR started');
            });
         } catch (e) {
            alert(e.message);
            return e.message;
        }
    }
    function confirmNewOrder(data) {
        try{
            alert('sending cofirmation');
            chat.SendNewOrderConfirmation(data);
            alert('confirmation sent');
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Did you registered the generated hub's javascript?

Comment: Hi Steve, how do I register it? Can you please paste some code. Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on the version of SignalR which you are using, the answer could be different.

To begin with, if you are on a version prior to v1 Alpha, then your code should be;

```
chat.sendNewOrderConfirmation(data);
```

Notice the lowercase `s`.

If you are on version v1 Alpha or greater, then you code should be;

```
chat.server.sendNewOrderConfirmation(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to register the hub's javascript generated file. Add this to your page (or your master page):

```
<script src="<%: ResolveUrl("~/signalr/hubs") %>"></script>
```

Comment: I did this, I can receive messages from server, I have problems sending them to the server